# React update parent component when child changes the Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have four React components:

- An overall parent (`App` or similar)
- A `Header` child, called by `App`
- A `Profile` page
- A `LogoutLink`, called by `Profile`

I am implementing a User authentication/login system using [Auth0](https://auth0.com). When the user logs in (via a Login button in the `Header`), `App` changes the `Context` of the `User` object to include all the data retrieved from Auth0. This user data is then accessible to any part of the system which requires it.

When logged in, the UI automatically updates (using `Context` changes) so that the `Header` is now showing "Hey there {name}" rather than "Login" as before. This is also a link leading to the `Profile` page/component (using React Router's `<Link to="/profile></Link>` element).

On the `Profile` page there is a `LogoutLink`. When clicked, this logs the user out, and returns to the home page. It should also update the UI automatically to change the message in the `Header` back from "Hey there {name}" to "Login". This is done by `Context` changes again. However, this feature doesn't actually work - the user is successfully logged out, but to see the change described just above, the user needs to refresh the whole page. **`this.context.user` is not being updated and sent back to `Profile` and `Header`.** I know this is because of Redux and it's one-way data flow (i.e data can only go downwards, not up), but I need to find a way around it.

Here is the basic code I have:

`LogoutLink.js`

```
export default class LogoutLink extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      user: null,
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    value: React.PropTypes.string,
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
  } // get context so this.context is available to get initial user data (before logout)

  static childContextTypes = {
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {user: this.state.user}
  } // these two are for updating context

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ user: this.context.user });
  } // set the internal LogoutLink state

  onClick() {
    this.setState({ user: null }); // set the internal user state to null following logout
  }

  renderLogoutLink() {
    const {value} = this.props;
    const {user} = this.state;
    if (user != null) {
      return <Link to="/profile" onClick={this.onClick}>{value}</Link>
    } else {
      return <span>You're already logged out!</span>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <span>{this.renderLogoutLink()}</span>
  }

}
```

`Header.js`:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showLock = this.showLock.bind(this); // lock is the Auth0 module responsible for Login, also passed down by context
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    user: React.PropTypes.object,
    lock: React.PropTypes.object,
  }

  showLock() {
    const {lock} = this.context;
    lock.show();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    if (this.context.user == null && nextContext.user != null) {
      return true;
    } else if (this.context.user != null && nextContext.user == null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } // after the LogoutLink is clicked, this still returns false

  renderLoginButton() {
    const {user} = this.context;
    if (user) {
      const name = user.nickname;
      return <Link to="/profile">Hey there {name}!</Link>
    } else {
      return <button onClick={this.showLock}>Login</button>
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        {this.renderLoginButton()}
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

I am following the official React docs about Context and updating it, found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

As I said I know why this is not working: data can only be sent one way. But I need to find a way to make this work, and to be honest I think I've been staring at this too long and am now out of options and my brain is a bit frazzled.

Comment: What is the value of nextContext coming in header shouldComponentUpdate .It should be the updated one
shouldComponentUpdate might be the culprit here. Please check the nextContext.user

Comment: Hi Piyush - `nextContext.user` is equal to the same as `this.context.user` int the `Header` component `shouldComponentUpdate` - it doesn't change when the `LogoutLink` changes the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this issue. In my `App.js` code, which is setting the initial context for the User item, I have added a method onto the User to set the User to null, which then trickles down through the app. In the Logout link it calls this method. Here is the code:

In `App.js`:

```
profile.logout = () => {
  this.setState({ profile: null });
}
```

the `getChildContext()` method then sets the user context from this state change:

```
getChildContext() {
  return {
    user: this.state.profile
  };
}
```

In `LogoutLink.js`:

```
onClick() {
  const {user} = this.context;
  user.logout(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The React "context" feature is useful, but also complicated and quirky, which is why there's still a number of cautions around using it.  In particular, I believe that components that return `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate` will cause lower components to not update if the context contents change.

My advice would be to use context as little as possible, and only for data that does *not* change.  Put changing data, such as the current user, into your Redux xtate.

Comment: Thanks Mark. While you say that a false `shouldComponentUpdate` will cause the lower components not to update, I have the opposite issue: I want a higher-up component to update when the context is changed by a lower down component. I think in a way (according to Redux) it makes sense as data should only flow down. But it's also annoying as context is theoretically supposed to be app-wide.

Comment: My understanding of context is admittedly still very hazy, so don't take this as gospel.  That said, I don't think that's how context works.  Context's purpose, as I understand it, is to let an ancestor make some mostly non-changing data available to any descendant that requests it. It's not "app-wide", unless it's something your very top component is exposing.  It's also not a way for a descendant to communicate with an ancestor.